# Round iOS button is deformed on some devices

Tags: ios

I used Swift to make a round button, but when it ran on the iPhone 13, it deformed, but it didn't deform on some other models

I created a 1:1 square button and set its properties like this

```
@IBOutlet weak var item: UIButton!
override func viewDidLoad() {
     super.viewDidLoad()

     item.layer.cornerRadius = item.frame.width/2
     item.clipsToBounds = true
 }
```

Setting the aspect ratio to 1:1 causes the round button to deform but I don't understand why.

[image]

Comment: write cornerRadius code inside the viewDidLayoutSubview method.

Comment: Thank you very much ，This method doesn't work for the problem, but I found that it becomes normal when it can be put into the viewdidappear function